# CodeIgniter autoroutingimproved feature

Tags: codeigniter-4

Newbie to CodeIgniter (4.4) here; I am trying to use autoroutingimproved feature of codeigniter documented [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=route#auto-routing-improved)

It mentions that it will not route to home/Foo as home is default route. Ok, then how do I get it to route to Foo() method? It goes on to say to delete Foo() method. In that sense the Home controller isn't expected to have any other methods?

Any ideas?

I tried setting up method getFoo(): string and expecting to route via http://mysite/Foo

It gives me error: Cannot access the default controller "\App\Controllers\Home::getFoo"

Note: have used c# routing in the past.

Comment: Where did you set up the getFoo() method? Inside the Home controller?

Comment: @Dusan I had also posted this in CI forums. Seems like only "index" is the method allowed in any default controllers like Home. So I had to create a Foo controller with an index method inside, and similar for every other method that I wanted to be placed at the root. Inconvenient but seems to be the only way as per Admins in CI forums.